# Tracing a crash through Flurry Analytics

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, error-handling, flurry

I am using Flurry analytics and i've noticed 1 or 2 people have been experiencing crashes and I really really want to fix it for them, however it's annoying as they haven't got in touch to tell me about the crash so I don't even know which viewController to investigate.

I'm using the following exception handler for flurry:

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    NSArray *backtrace = [exception callStackSymbols];
    NSString *platform = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
    NSString *version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device: %@. OS: %@. Backtrace:\n%@",
                         platform,
                         version,
                         backtrace];

    [Flurry logError:@"Uncaught" message:message exception:exception];
}
```

however the backtrace gets truncated and all I get is this:

> NSRangeException: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond
>   bounds [0 .. 1] Msg: Device: iPad. OS: 5.1.1. Backtrace: ( 0
>   CoreFoundation 0x32b5e8a7 __exceptionPreprocess + 186 1
>   libobjc.A.dylib 0x34b03259 objc_exception_throw + 32 2 CoreFoundation
>   0x32aa79db -[__NSA

which doesn't really help me.

Are there any other methods I could use to track and report back the error?
Or maybe at the very least is it possible to show a message on the screen at the point of a crash so I can add a message to please get in touch?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Flurry provides Full Stack Trace crash reports for Android apps through their new SDK v3.x. This feature will soon be introduced for iOS apps as well. For any further details, please write to support@flurry.com (Full Disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)

Comment: That would be excellent. Any idea of when it will be available?

Comment: @Aman PLease check this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476056/flurry-not-generateing-error-or-crash-log

Answer (score 0):

The new version of Flurry SDK (>= v4.3) now supports [Crash Analytics](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/FAQ/CrashAnalytics) so I think the use of `uncaughtExceptionHandler` is not necessary anymore.