# Flurry not generateing error or crash log?

Tags: ios, xcode5, flurry

I am using the latest Flurry SDK 4.3.2, and in this I am getting all the `logEvent` which I register, but I am not getting any kind of Crash Report or Error log in flurry.

```
    [Flurry logEvent:FLURRY_APP_LAUCHED timed:YES];
    [Flurry setLogLevel:FlurryLogLevelNone];
    [Flurry setCrashReportingEnabled:YES];
    [Flurry startSession:@"=====My App KEY===="];
```

I have tried this even with the Forced crashed on multiple devices. Still unable to get the log.

I am using XCODE 5.0.

Does anyone else face this type of problem?